# zoomify equivalent in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, slider, zooming, viewer

I've been searching for quite some time for a rough equivalent of Zoomify (zoomify.com) for jQuery-- that is, a zoomable image viewer with slider. I'm aware of AjaxZoom, but I find the interface clunky, and the feature set beyond what I really need. Through this site, I found [jQuery gzoom](http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/) which is much closer to what I'm looking for, but I wish it could be modified to match the behavior/functionality of something like Zoomify, i.e. with smooth dragging and panning enabled by click, as opposed to hovering over the image, as well as a button to reset the view to default.

If anyone is aware of a plugin out there that meets this description or is even capable of modifying the gzoom script-- my JavaScript knowledge is limited-- I'd be most appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: Its not jQuery, but Microsoft has a pure JavaScript version of Seadragon that might be worth checking out: http://www.seadragon.com/developer/ajax/

Comment: thanks dana-- that's really great! any way to add a slider to control zoom level?

Answer (score 1):

I've researched all the above mentioned options and found significant limitations in all of them. Looks like all vendors that dominated this space years ago are running out of steam and not investing enough in touch experience.
But I found a new product that looks promising: http://www.starplugins.com/starzoom
I tested their demos on iOS, Android and a few PC browsers and found that they work fine, touch friendly, and very lightweight. If anybody here used StarZoom please share your experience.

Comment: hi Dennis-- wow, that does look promising; thanks for the link. I'll have to take a look myself...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is one.  I've looked too.  [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) is pure JavaScript and is pretty slick.  It comes pretty close to the Zoomify functionality.  You can even use [images prepared with Zoomify](http://ttp://oldmapsonline.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/openlayers/examples/zoomify.html) with OpenLayers.

There's also [openzoom](http://openzoom.org/), but it lacks the nice UI controls that Zoomify and OpenLayers have.

Comment: thanks todd, I will look into those examples; I was also trying to locate the script behind the zoom functionality on this page: http://www.endclothing.co.uk/comme-des-garcons-play-double-heart-logo-tee-20.html ... that's almost exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: endclothing site uses this: http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom.htm

Answer (score 0):

The interface of AjaxZoom can be disabled or adjusted, see this example:

http://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example16.php